# how to get Visual C++ 2013 to highlight (underline) errors as I enter code

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++

As I enter C code, I want Visual Studio to immediately highlight errors as I type them.  But it doesn't do it.  No red underline or nothing.

I could not find a command to do this in tools menu > Text Editor > c/c++ > Advanced and other sections.

Comment: It should do this by default. What happens when you reset your IDE configuration?

Comment: You're right.  I must have turned it off when I was editing Matlab .m code a while back.   I just need to find the Tools > Options ... that controls this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tools menu > Options command > Text Editor option > C/C++ > Advanced > IntelliSense > Disable Squiggles set to False

Comment: I answer the question, and get a down-vote.  Sheesh.